# How to remove float point, if value is exponent

Tags: php

Just remove the float point,
no round, floor or ceil.

This is my current function

```
    function float_to_integer($v)
    {
        return((int)str_replace('.', '', strval(1.0 * $v)));
    };
```

ok, it's simple,
find out the float point,
and replace it to empty,
it normally works fine as below:

```
    float_to_integer(0.123) 
      => 123 

    float_to_integer(1.234) 
      => 1234
```

but when the value is very small,
for example, 10^-5

```
    float_to_integer(0.00001) 
      => 0
--------
what!?
why not return 1
```

After my checking,
when I call

```
float_to_integer(0.00001)
```

it actually do as follow

```
float_to_integer(10E-5)
```

the float value has NO float point, lol,
my function failed...

So, the question is,

```
is there a way to remove float value that in exponent case?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast it as string before calling the function, if you're going to apply `str_replace` to it.

You could use:

```
function float_to_integer($v)
{
    return((int)str_replace('.', '', $v));
}

$v = 0.00001;
$v = sprintf("%.5f", $v);        // returns string(7) "0.00001"
$result =  float_to_integer($v); // returns int(1)
```

But then you need to know how many decimal digits there are after the floating point to put instead of `"%.5f"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it doesn't solve my problem directly, but give me the direction to go and it's done finally!!  : )